# python: Add a method with parameters with class decorator results in TypeError: add_bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

This is my code:

```
class MyInp(int):
    pass

def add_bar(cls, input_type):
    def bar(self, inp :input_type):
        print(f"bar: {inp}")

    setattr(cls, 'bar', bar)
    return cls

@add_bar(input_type=MyInp)
class Foo():
   pass

f = Foo()
f.bar(3)
```

running this returns:

> TypeError: add_bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'

I know i can call `add_bar` after class definition (`add_bar(Foo, MyInp)`) and it will work
but how do i add a method that takes multiple params without needing to specify the class that is not yet defined?
or can i do something else like register the input_type and in some magical way when the class is defined it can deduce it's input_type and declare the method?

Answer (score 1):

The short aswer is:

```
class MyInp(int):
    pass

def add_bar(input_type):
    def add_bar_impl(cls):
        def bar(self, inp :input_type):
            print(f"bar: {inp}")

        setattr(cls, 'bar', bar)
        return cls
    return add_bar_impl

@add_bar(input_type=MyInp)
class Foo():
   pass

f = Foo()
f.bar(3)
```

A longer explanation is available [here](http://xtianpoli.github.io/python-tinkering/avances.html#exercice-suite) unfortunately in french ...

Comment: Beautiful, so basically it's like the class is decorated with `add_bar_impl`?

Comment: Yes. add_bar is just a function which returns the actual decorator add_bar_impl. Its role is to put input_type variable in the closure of add_bar_impl.